# Website binaries in asp.net website project?

Tags: asp.net, dll, web, binary, project

I hate to ask such a stupid question but i couldnt find the answer on Google. I can successfully build a large website project with lots of asp.net code but i dont know where the binaries are being kept so i can upload it a development server.

I checked the bin folder but and they only seem to contain library dlls.

Answer (score 3):

you need to do "publish web site" to make all the code into DLL file.

BTW , evry time you publish your website , all the binary name are changing.. so you will need to re-copy ALL your web site again to the server...

NOTE: you will need to full Visual studio version to do publish..

Comment: If you use aspnet_compiler -fixednames it'll give you the same names for your DLL files every time you compile